# Цикл while в SQL

Tags: sql

Здравствуйте!

Попробовал простенький цикл while, посмотрите, в чем ошибка - не пойму...

```
USE aaa go WHILE (SELECT * FROM t4 WHERE ch3<2) BEGIN UPDATE t4 SET ch4=ch4+1 
break END
```

Comment: какой диалект. while break и т.д. - это не SQL, это его расширения

Comment: Судя по всему Transact-SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(select * from t4 where ch3<2)` - это условие, но оно оформлено неверно, не логическое условие. Как я понимаю, нужно добавить EXISTS:

```
while EXISTS(select * from t4 where ch3<2)
```